# use of partially moved value: `self` in closure

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker

I have a struct  in rust:

```
pub struct Application {
    name: String,
    windows: Vec<Window>,
    event_loop: EventLoop<()>,
}
```

in here I have a method which moves self and runs an event loop which takes a move closure. I still want to reference self, as it has some methods I need to run according to events. It looks like this

```
    pub fn run(mut self) {
        self.event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| match event {
            Event::WindowEvent {
                window_id,
                ..
            } => {
                &self.send_event_to_window(window_id, event);
            },
            Event::RedrawRequested(window_id) => {
                &self.send_event_to_window(window_id, event);
            }
            Event::MainEventsCleared => {
                // RedrawRequested will only trigger once, unless we manually
                // request it.
                // state.window().request_redraw();
            }
            _ => {},
        });
    }
```

rust has an issue with me using self.send_event_to_window and says
"use of partially moved value: `self`"

How do I access self from this closure? Im not sure even why rust doesn't let me use it as I move it into the closure.

Comment: _"Im not sure even why rust doesn't let me use it as I move it into the closure."_ -- You moved `self` into the closure, which means it can no longer be used anywhere except in the closure. But then you call `run` on it.

Comment: What prompted you to use the `move` keyword here?

Comment: Assuming you are using `winit`, take a look at the examples. None of them are structured the way that your code is. e.g. https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/blob/master/examples/drag_window.rs

Comment: `You moved self into the closure, which means it can no longer be used anywhere except in the closure.` yeah exactly, but im trying to use it in the closure calling `&self.send_event_to_window`

Comment: Why did you make `event_loop` a field of your application struct? Ask yourself if it's necessary. And look at the `winit` examples for ideas.

Comment: To make more windows for the same application possible. Event loop is a "singleton" (creating more than 1 instance of it panics the program) and hence when windows is created, I pass it the only reference of event loop that application holds.

Of course the examples of winit are not structured this way - they are examples of using winit, not structuring the code around it.

Comment: But why does that mean you need to make it a field of Application? Other examples of `winit` have multiple windows and don't do that. For e.g https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/blob/master/examples/multithreaded.rs

Comment: What I'm getting at is that this is likely an X/Y problem. If you follow the pattern for how the makers of this crate expect it to be used then your problem no longer exists. Sure, someone could help you make it work a bit more like you have presented it, but that would probably end up being a worse solution than just building it the right way.

Comment: I understand, but the examples show a static number of windows. What if I want to add window in the runtime? I have to pass it a reference to event_loop. Here's what i dont get. I'm new to rust and it is my second language after Java. In java storing a simple variable and working with it is such a simple thing I wouldn't ever think it would be this kind of struggle. Having simple event loop var, running it and  referencing it when i need to

Comment: The issue is that the closure has access to `self`, so it has access to `event_loop` while it's actively being used. One approach to solve this is to use an `Option` like so: `event_loop: Option<EventLoop<()>>,`  and then [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) it out of `self` before calling `event_loop.run()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `self.eventLoop.run` in `Application.run`, then `EventLoop.run` has ownership of `self.eventLoop` (partial ownership of `self`). As such the closure cannot call any method on `self`, because such a method might use `self.eventLoop`.

There are a couple of ways of fixing this:

1. Make `event_loop` a local variable in the `run` function
2. Make `event_loop` a parameter of the `run` function
3. Put the variables needed by `event_loop` into a separate struct like so:

```rs
pub struct ApplicationState {
  name: String,
  windows: Vec<Window>,
  // put anything that needs to be accessible by the run closure here
}
impl ApplicationState {
 // implement functions that do not use event_loop here
 // these can be called by the run closure
 fn send_event_to_window(window_id, event) {}
}
pub struct Application {
  state: ApplicationState,
  event_loop: EventLoop<()>,
}
impl Application {
      pub fn run(mut self) {
        self.event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| match event {
            Event::WindowEvent {
                window_id,
                ..
            } => {
                &self.state.send_event_to_window(window_id, event);
            },
            Event::RedrawRequested(window_id) => {
                &self.state.send_event_to_window(window_id, event);
            }
            Event::MainEventsCleared => {
                // RedrawRequested will only trigger once, unless we manually
                // request it.
                // state.window().request_redraw();
            }
            _ => {},
        });
    }
}
```